# rectangle disappearing with SDL

Tags: c++, sdl

So I'm simply trying to make a red 10 x 10 box move vertically back and forth. I compile and run my program and the red box appears starts moving down, then just disappears after it hits the edge of the screen. I used some `cout <<` statements that tell me when the functions are being called and they are all being called when they are supposed to. Even when the box can't be seen the functions are properly being called.

## My main loop

```
while(running) 

    {

        myScreen->Clear();

        boxes.Move();

        boxes.Draw();

        myScreen->Flip();
                ........
```

## My draw() function

```
   SDL_Color red;
   red.r = 255;
   red.g = 0;
   red.b = 0;
   if( SDL_FillRect( my_screen->Get_screen(), &start_dest, SDL_MapRGB( 
   my_screen->Get_pixel_format(), red.r, red.g, red.b ) ) == -1 )`
      cout << "Fill rect in Draw(); failed\n";
```

## My Move() function

```
start_dest.y += y_step;
if ( start_dest.y >= my_screen->Get_height() )
   {
      cout << "start_dest.y >= screen height\n";
      start_dest.y = my_screen->Get_height();
      y_step = -y_step;
   }
   if ( start_dest.y <= 0 )
   {
      cout << "start_dest.y <= 0\n";
      start_dest.y = 0;
      y_step = -y_step;
   }
```

I have been trying to find this bug forever. just leave a comment if anyone wants to see more code. Thanks

Comment: Just a little tip: if you use an actual debugger you'll find bugs much much much faster and in a much much much cleaner way than filling your program with `cout`s.

Comment: Perhaps the bug is caused by an excess of exclamation marks in the source code.

Comment: Please tell me: what value goes Get_height() return, and what is initial value of y_step. It looks to me like they speak in different units, and then getheight is never reached and the direction is never reversed.

Comment: Get_height() returns the height of the screen, and y_step starts at 1, and i have been using cout statements and the direction does change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't enough information to give conclusive answer, but here's a hint.

From my experience with SDL, SDL functions can modify your Rect structure when called, especially when rect is partly off-screen. Make sure you set **all** its properties (x,y,width,height) before **each** SDL function that uses the rectangle.

Comment: Yep i simply added a start_dest.h = 10; before my SDL_fillRect and it worked! thanks

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming here that start_dest has a 'height' member, and that the screen coordinates have (0,0) in the top left corner)

I think perhaps the first 'if' statement in Move() should be

```
if(start_dest.y >= my_screen.Get_height - start_dest.height)
```

so that the rectangle will bounce when its bottom hits the bottom of the screen rather than waiting until the top of the rectangle gets there.  Something to that effect, anyways.